# How to make hyperlinked Photoshop slices look better?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I'm making a onesheet in Photoshop and it requires web links. I had no idea how to do that so I looked up a tutorial or whatever that said if you make slices, you can add hyperlinks to each individual slice, then save it for web. So I did that and it works just fine, I can open it up and all the links work, but here's the thing. I made it a large file, pixel-wise, because I figured it would look better if you took a big thing and zoomed out rather than taking a small thing and zooming in. But when I open the file in Chrome and zoom out, the slices seem to shift around slightly. There are jagged spots where there were previously straight lines and there are visible spots of white between the slices. What do I do about this? Do I need to use a different method for the links? Do I make the document smaller?

I'm hardly an expert here, so try to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

When you view sites at non-default zooms, the images may appear awkward, but you can reduce it by either setting the background to the color of the links images (if they have a consistent solid color around) or, re-export (save) all your image slices in the PNG format with a transparent background.

If you use the PNG method, it does not matter how often you zoom, there wont be any awkward (and irritating) spaces between the slices.